# Swap icon to show relevant expand or collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that will expland and collapse content. This code originally replaced the header with Expand/Collapse (commented out below) but what I want to have is an image or text (+ / -) as relevant next to a unique h2 tag.

the script is:

```
$(".header").click(function () {

$header = $(this);
//getting the next element
$content = $header.next();
//open up the content needed
$content.slideToggle(500, function () {
    //execute this after slideToggle is done
    //change text of header based on visibility of content div
    //$header.text(function () {
        //change text based on condition
        //return $content.is(":visible") ? "-" : "+";
    //});
});
});
```

the content looks like

```
<div class="header">
      <h2>The Role</h2>
      </div>
<div class="content">
      <?php the_field('the_role')?>
</div>
<div class="header">
      <h2>Your Experience</h2>
      </div>
<div class="content">
      <?php the_field('your_experience')?>
</div>
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: $(this).text() will get the header text which you can modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, I think this is what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/wf_4/NJR22/

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <span>-</span>  
    <h2>The Role</h2>
</div>
<div class="content">
    text here
</div>
<div class="header">
    <span>-</span>  
    <h2>Your Experience</h2>
</div>
<div class="content">
    text here
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(".header").click(function () {

    var $header = $(this),
        $span = $header.find(">:first-child"),
    //getting the next element
        $content = $header.next();
    //open up the content needed
    $content.slideToggle(500)

    if ($span.text() == "-")
        $span.text("+")
    else {
        $span.text("-")
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.header > span {
    float:left;
    width:20px

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix your current problem. This would work

```
$(function() {
$('.header').each(function() {
   if( $(this).next('div.content').length > 0 ) {
       $(this).prepend('<img src="collapsed.png" class="collapser" />');
   }
});
});

$(".header").click(function () {

$header = $(this);
//getting the next element
$content = $header.next();
//open up the content needed

$content.slideToggle(500, function () {
    //execute this after slideToggle is done
    //change text of header based on visibility of content div
    //$header.text(function () {
        //change text based on condition
          if( $content.is(":visible") ) {
            $header.find('.collapser').attr('src','collapsed.png');
           } else {
             $header.find('.collapser').attr('src','expanded.png');
           }
        //return $content.is(":visible") ? "-" : "+";
    //});
});
});
```

I would refactor if i were you, and do like this
**HTML**

```
<div class="accordio">
    <div class="header">
        <img src="collapsed.png" class="collapser" />
          <h2>The Role</h2>
     </div>
    <div class="content">
          ss
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordio">
    <div class="header">
          <img src="collapsed.png" class="collapser" />
          <h2>Your experience</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
          ss
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(".accordio .header").click(function () {
$header = $(this);
$content = $header.parent().find('.content');
$content.slideToggle(500, function () {
          if( $content.is(":visible") ) {
            $header.find('.collapser').attr('src','collapsed.png');
           } else {
             $header.find('.collapser').attr('src','expanded.png');
           }
});
});
```